# How to move a button background?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having trouble moving a button background. I've identified the class which enables me to move the button text anywhere I like, but I want the  button background to move with it.

Html:

```
<li class="location"><a class="google_map_link" 
href="http://maps.google.com/maps?  
q=London&#038;zoom=14&#038;size=512x512&#038;
maptype=roadmap&#038;sensor=false">London</a></li>
```

Tried css:

```
.google_map_link {margin-top: 10px;}
```

This works for the text but background and `fafa` stay in same place??

https://adsler.co.uk/job/holland-and-barratt-london-4-store-colleague

Comment: `.google_map_link` is only your text. If you want to move everything, you need to edit the `<li>` element or the `.location` class.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. As i understand`.location` controls maps button for another plugin and operates under a separate div?

Comment: Did you write this HTML code? If you have control over it, just put an ID as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your message.. Didn't write it. It's a plugin. Have control but reluctant to edit a plugin directly. Rather use css if poss?

Comment: I see...looks like `.location` is only used for that button in this specific page. If you can put CSS only on that page, you could use the `.location` class. If not, you would need to create your own ID in a parent component and navigate to that using CSS selections, like `#my-custom-id > div .location`

Comment: Another option is to post here your HTML post and how you are using the plugin. You can probably fix what you want without touching the plugin or overwriting its CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your background and icon not move because first has fixed height and second has vertical-align

```
.location {
...
height: 24px;
}
.single_job_listing .meta .location:before {
...
vertical-align: top;
}
```

disable those styles and they move with text when you add `.google_map_link {margin-top: 10px;}`

Comment: But that will change all my buttons under div `.location`?

Comment: Can't i do`google_map_link {height:unset vertical-align: unset;`?

Comment: You can add your any class like `<li class="location my-location-li">` and write style:
`.my-location-li .location {height:auto;}
.single_job_listing .meta .location.my-location-li:before{vertical-align: unset;}`. Check [css selectors](https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/css-selectors/)

Comment: Tried what you said in your answer. Now the background selects but doesn't move. `margin-top 10px;` just makes the button larger on top by 10px;

Comment: @One89 Describe with details what do you want to do with button and what do you mean "move background"? Maybe I didn't understand your post correctly.

Comment: Ok.  No probs. So my button is pushed up against a picture at the top, and up against a border at the bottom. I want to move it 10 to 15px down the page as it's too close to the picture. Perhaps also push the border below down or create a margin/padding at the bottom of the button. All my button styled links appear to be behaving like this, with just the text moving when i select the div. Before, as soon as i selected the div class, the text, fafa, and button background would move together. What's changed in my css to make just the text move? Thanks.

Comment: @One89 Are you want to do something with button stile, when you click some block, or when the users pointer hovers over sumething?
This is [pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). You write "with just the text moving when i select the div". What div, wherу is it? maybe you can write class of this div?

Comment: @One89 Or if you want to move button static?
This button is inside "ul" with classes "job-listing-meta meta".
You can move all: `.single_job_listing .meta li {margin: 10px;}`
Or just top: `.single_job_listing .meta li {margin: 10px 0 0 0;}`
Or move just one this button: `.single_job_listing .meta li.location {margin: 10px;}`
Also remove margin-top inside .google_map_link. It is more beatiful to move txt inside button with pudding, like: `.single_job_listing .meta li.location {padding: 10px;}`.

Comment: @One89 Also i am recommend you to reading some css [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS) or find video

Answer (score -1):

You can use background-position to rearrange a background image

```
.google_map_link {
   background-position:0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but isn't there a simpler way? All my buttons are doing it now...

Comment: You could add an id to the button you want to change and then use background-position on that id

Comment: He is not using a background image, you can see in the link that was posted. Please update or remove your answer :)